# Rails , a controller can correspond to more than one model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use rails to make a website , now I want a controller which has multiple pages, and each page fetches the data from different data table,how can I do this?

Comment: yes. you can do this

Answer (score 3):

This is absolutely possible.  The reason you don't see it in tutorials, or just very often, is because Rails is built on the concept of REST.  So, this behavior isn't advised for a number of reasons.  However, if you want, here is a general outline of steps.

This requires multiple steps:

1.) Generate a controller.  `rails generate controller <name>`

2.) Create routing and corresponding actions in the controller you generated.

ie. In `routes.rb` you declare the url, controller to handle it (use the one you just generated), and action (a method within a controller)

3.) In each action, reach out to whatever database table you want.  If your DB has posts, tags, and comments as tables, for example...

```
Class YourController < ApplicationController
  def action1
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def action2
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  def action3
    @tags = Tag.all
  end
end
```

Now, `action1` will expect a view called `action1.html.erb`, and the same for the other two actions.  When you go the url for `action 1` that you set up in `routes.rb`, it will render the html and erb code from that view.

This is very in depth question, and this is a brief overview of the steps.  There are alot of great resources to get started with Rails.

Ryan Bate's Railscasts are awesome.
The edge guides are also solid: [edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/)